# Implementing the Passport in lumen

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, lumen, laravel-passport

I am trying to implement [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport) in [lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/).

I am using [lumen-passport](https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/lumen-passport) package, i did successfully install the package in lumen, did configuration as given in documentation.

The response i get is blank or Unauthorized, in api's.

In postmen, Get method

```
/oauth/tokens
```

Gives `Unauthorized.` in response.

In postmen, Post method

```
/oauth/token

'grant_type' => 'password',
'client_id' => 'client-id',
'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
'username' => 'test@laravel.com',
'password' => 'my-password',
'scope' => '',
```

Getting response blank.

And having same problem with other api's.

Any one having same problem or know what could have gone wrong.

Comment: check the middle wares

Answer (score 0):

You must add `access_token` to the headers.

Comment: can you elaborate?